No module named qiskit-algorithm
I want to try the quantum computing simulator, but when I try to import the Algorithm, the Qiskit shows an error. For your information, I am currently running Qiskit using Google Colab.
This is the code:
from qiskit.algorithms import AmplificationProblem
from qiskit.algorithms.amplitude_amplifiers import Grover

But the output is
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.algorithms'


Does this answer your question?

Just install qiskit-algorithms via pip:
pip install qiskit-algorithms

A sample code of that package can be found here.
from qiskit_algorithms import AmplificationProblem
from qiskit_algorithms.amplitude_amplifiers import Grover
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler

# the state we desire to find is '11'
good_state = ["11"]

# specify the oracle that marks the state '11' as a good solution
oracle = QuantumCircuit(2)
oracle.cz(0, 1)

# define Grover's algorithm
problem = AmplificationProblem(oracle, is_good_state=good_state)

grover = Grover(sampler=Sampler())
result = grover.amplify(problem)
print("Success!" if result.oracle_evaluation else "Failure!")
print("Top measurement:", result.top_measurement)

Success!
Top measurement: 11

